# Why is lambda return type not checked at compile time?

Tags: java, generics, lambda, type-inference, method-reference

The used method reference has return type `Integer`. But an incompatible `String` is allowed in the following example.

How to fix the method `with` declaration to get the method reference type safe without manually casting?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class MinimalExample {
  static public class Builder<T> {
    final Class<T> clazz;

    Builder(Class<T> clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    static <T> Builder<T> of(Class<T> clazz) {
      return new Builder<T>(clazz);
    }

    <R> Builder<T> with(Function<T, R> getter, R returnValue) {
      return null; //TODO
    }

  }

  static public interface MyInterface {
    Integer getLength();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
// missing compiletimecheck is inaceptable:
    Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with(MyInterface::getLength, "I am NOT an Integer");

// compile time error OK: 
    Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with((Function<MyInterface, Integer> )MyInterface::getLength, "I am NOT an Integer");
// The method with(Function<MinimalExample.MyInterface,R>, R) in the type MinimalExample.Builder<MinimalExample.MyInterface> is not applicable for the arguments (Function<MinimalExample.MyInterface,Integer>, String)
  }

}
```

---

### USE CASE: a type safe but generic Builder.

I tried to implement a generic builder without annotation processing (autovalue) or compiler plugin (lombok)

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Proxy;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class BuilderExample {
  static public class Builder<T> implements InvocationHandler {
    final Class<T> clazz;
    HashMap<Method, Object> methodReturnValues = new HashMap<>();

    Builder(Class<T> clazz) {
      this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    static <T> Builder<T> of(Class<T> clazz) {
      return new Builder<T>(clazz);
    }

    Builder<T> withMethod(Method method, Object returnValue) {
      Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
      if (returnType.isPrimitive()) {
        if (returnValue == null) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("Primitive value cannot be null:" + method);
        } else {
          try {
            boolean isConvertable = getDefaultValue(returnType).getClass().isAssignableFrom(returnValue.getClass());
            if (!isConvertable) {
              throw new ClassCastException(returnValue.getClass() + " cannot be cast to " + returnType + " for " + method);
            }
          } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        }
      } else if (returnValue != null && !returnType.isAssignableFrom(returnValue.getClass())) {
        throw new ClassCastException(returnValue.getClass() + " cannot be cast to " + returnType + " for " + method);
      }
      Object previuos = methodReturnValues.put(method, returnValue);
      if (previuos != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value alread set for " + method);
      }
      return this;
    }

    static HashMap<Class, Object> defaultValues = new HashMap<>();

    private static <T> T getDefaultValue(Class<T> clazz) {
      if (clazz == null || !clazz.isPrimitive()) {
        return null;
      }
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      T cachedDefaultValue = (T) defaultValues.get(clazz);
      if (cachedDefaultValue != null) {
        return cachedDefaultValue;
      }
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      T defaultValue = (T) Array.get(Array.newInstance(clazz, 1), 0);
      defaultValues.put(clazz, defaultValue);
      return defaultValue;
    }

    public synchronized static <T> Method getMethod(Class<T> clazz, java.util.function.Function<T, ?> resolve) {
      AtomicReference<Method> methodReference = new AtomicReference<>();
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      T proxy = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { clazz }, new InvocationHandler() {

        @Override
        public Object invoke(Object p, Method method, Object[] args) {

          Method oldMethod = methodReference.getAndSet(method);
          if (oldMethod != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Method was already called " + oldMethod);
          }
          Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
          return getDefaultValue(returnType);
        }
      });

      resolve.apply(proxy);
      Method method = methodReference.get();
      if (method == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException(new NoSuchMethodException());
      }
      return method;
    }

    // R will accep common type Object :-( // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337639
    <R, V extends R> Builder<T> with(Function<T, R> getter, V returnValue) {
      Method method = getMethod(clazz, getter);
      return withMethod(method, returnValue);
    }

    //typesafe :-) but i dont want to avoid implementing all types
    Builder<T> withValue(Function<T, Long> getter, long returnValue) {
      return with(getter, returnValue);
    }

    Builder<T> withValue(Function<T, String> getter, String returnValue) {
      return with(getter, returnValue);
    }

    T build() {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      T proxy = (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { clazz }, this);
      return proxy;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) {
      Object returnValue = methodReturnValues.get(method);
      if (returnValue == null) {
        Class<?> returnType = method.getReturnType();
        return getDefaultValue(returnType);
      }
      return returnValue;
    }
  }

  static public interface MyInterface {
    String getName();

    long getLength();

    Long getNullLength();

    Long getFullLength();

    Number getNumber();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyInterface x = Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with(MyInterface::getName, "1").with(MyInterface::getLength, 1L).with(MyInterface::getNullLength, null).with(MyInterface::getFullLength, new Long(2)).with(MyInterface::getNumber, 3L).build();
    System.out.println("name:" + x.getName());
    System.out.println("length:" + x.getLength());
    System.out.println("nullLength:" + x.getNullLength());
    System.out.println("fullLength:" + x.getFullLength());
    System.out.println("number:" + x.getNumber());

    // java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to long:
    // RuntimeException only :-(
    MyInterface y = Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with(MyInterface::getLength, "NOT A NUMBER").build();

    // java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
    // RuntimeException only :-(
    System.out.println("length:" + y.getLength());
  }

}
```

Comment: surprising behaviour. Out of interest: is it the same when you use a `class` instead of an `interface` for the builder?

Comment: Why is that unacceptable? In the first case, you don't give the type of the `getLength`, so it can be adjusted to return `Object` (or `Serializable`) to match the String parameter.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I think your method `with` is part of the problem as it returns `null` . When implementing the method `with()` by actually using the function's `R` type as the same `R` from the parameter you get the error. For example `<R> R with(Function<T, R> getter, T input, R returnValue) { return getter.apply(input); }`

Comment: @GameDroids the behavior would be the same, despite the `class` or an `interface` as long as they are represented as a `FunctionalInterface`, using a lambda/method-reference.

Comment: @Naman, thanks for the clarification. What about my implementation (comment above), why does it give me the error. Is it the same effect you described in your answer, that `R` suddenly became *specific*?

Comment: @Naman is there any lambdas so we need that tag?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Well, the type inference would be same and the lambda tag existed. I guess my edits are little latent to reflect, hence they changed yours further.

Comment: @Naman with() is not intended to return R. Thats another usecase.

Comment: @Thilo the behaviour is unaceptable as it will later result in a Runtimerror in the implementation. My desire is to build a typesafe but generic Builder pattern

Comment: jukzi, maybe you should provide code or an explanation about what your with method should actually do and why you need `R` to be `Integer`. For this, you need to show us how you want to utilize the return value. It seems that you want to implement some kind of builder-pattern, but I can not recognize a common pattern or your intention.

Comment: If you want this to be typesafe, you have to include the `R` in the type signature somewhere. As it stands `with` just returns a `Builder<T>`, completely ignoring the type `R`. If it returned something related to `R`, you would get an error if you try to assign that `R` to `Integer` when it is actually a `Comparable & Serializable`. But for that to work, you need to "preserve" the `R` somewhere on the type returned from `with`.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve a fully compile-time type-checked builder without actually doing things at compile-time (via compiler plugin or annotation processing or source code generation).

Comment: That solution is pretty cool actually. Looks a lot like what mocking libraries do. I suppose the next achievement to unlock is making sure you have called `with` for all methods that the interface has (and maybe not called `with` for a method that is not even in the interface).

Comment: Thanks. I also thought about checking for complete initialization. But since i see no way to do it at compile time i prefer to stick with the default values null/0. I have also no idea how to check for non interface methods at compile time. At runtime using an non interface like ".with(m -> 1).returning(1)" already results in an early java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Comment: I wonder what happens if the signature was `<R> Builder<T, RV extends R> with(Function<T, R> getter, RV returnValue)`, which deduces the two types seprarately?

Comment: @MooingDuck That does not scala up to chaining multiple `with`. There was a solution with an intermediate "method builder object" for a while, you can see it in the edit history. (update: it's here now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58351892/14955)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the first example, `MyInterface::getLength` and `"I am NOT an Integer"` helped to resolve the generic parameters `T` and `R` to `MyInterface` and `Serializable & Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>`respectively.

```
// it compiles since String is a Serializable
Function<MyInterface, Serializable> function = MyInterface::getLength;
Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with(function, "I am NOT an Integer");
```

`MyInterface::getLength` is not always a `Function<MyInterface, Integer>` unless you explicitly say so, which would lead to a compile-time error as the second example showed.

```
// it doesn't compile since String isn't an Integer
Function<MyInterface, Integer> function = MyInterface::getLength;
Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with(function, "I am NOT an Integer");
```

Comment: This answer fully answers the question why it is interpreted other then intendet. Interesting. Sounds like R is useless. Do you know any solution to the Problem?

Comment: @jukzi (1) explicitly define method type parameters (here, `R`): `Builder.of(MyInterface.class).<Integer>with(MyInterface::getLength, "I am NOT an Integer");` to make it not compile, or (2) let it gets resolved implicitly and hopefully proceed with no compile-time errors

Answer (score 11):

It is because your generic type parameter `R` can be inferred to be Object, i.e. the following compiles:

```
Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with((Function<MyInterface, Object>) MyInterface::getLength, "I am NOT an Integer");
```

Comment: Exactly, if OP assigned the result of the method to a variable of type `Integer`, that would be where the compilation error happens.

Comment: @sepp2k Except that the `Builder` is only generic in `T`, but not in `R`. This `Integer` is just being ignored as far as type-checking the builder is concerned.

Comment: *`R` is inferred to be `Object`* ... not really

Comment: @Thilo You're right, of course. I assumed the return type of `with` would use `R`. Of course that means there is no meaningful way to actually implement that method in a way that actually uses the arguments.

Comment: Naman, you are right , you and Andrew answered it in more detail with the correct inferred type. I just wanted to give a simpler explanation (although anyone looking at this question probably knows type inference and other types than just `Object`).

Comment: This answer is the most easy to understand and fully answers the question why it goes wrong. Do you know any solution to the Problem?

Answer (score 11):

Its the type inference that is playing its role here. Consider the generic `R` in the method signature:

```
<R> Builder<T> with(Function<T, R> getter, R returnValue)
```

In the case as listed:

```
Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with(MyInterface::getLength, "I am NOT an Integer");
```

the type of `R` is successfully inferred as

```
Serializable, Comparable<? extends Serializable & Comparable<?>>
```

and a `String` does imply by this type, hence the compilation succeeds.

---

To explicitly specify the type of `R` and find out the incompatibility, one can simply change the line of code as :

```
Builder.of(MyInterface.class).<Integer>with(MyInterface::getLength, "not valid");
```

Comment: Explicitly declaring R as <Integer> is interesting and fully answers the question why it goes wrong. However i am still searching for a solution without declaring the Type explicit. Any Idea?

Comment: @jukzi What kind of solution are you looking for? The code already compiles, if you want to use it as it. An example of what you're looking for would be good to make things clear further.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the other answers which explain why it does not work as expected.

### SOLUTION

The following code solves the problem by splitting the bifunction "with" into two fluent functions "with" and "returning":

```
class Builder<T> {
...
class BuilderMethod<R> {
  final Function<T, R> getter;

  BuilderMethod(Function<T, R> getter) {
    this.getter = getter;
  }

  Builder<T> returning(R returnValue) {
    return Builder.this.with(getter, returnValue);
  }
}

<R> BuilderMethod<R> with(Function<T, R> getter) {
  return new BuilderMethod<>(getter);
}
...
}

MyInterface z = Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with(MyInterface::getLength).returning(1L).with(MyInterface::getNullLength).returning(null).build();
System.out.println("length:" + z.getLength());

// YIPPIE COMPILATION ERRROR:
// The method returning(Long) in the type BuilderExample.Builder<BuilderExample.MyInterface>.BuilderMethod<Long> is not applicable for the arguments (String)
MyInterface zz = Builder.of(MyInterface.class).with(MyInterface::getLength).returning("NOT A NUMBER").build();
System.out.println("length:" + zz.getLength());
```

(is somewhat unfamiliar)

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376589/ for a direct solution