# Why is a type parameter stronger then a method parameter

Tags: java, generics, lambda, type-inference

Why is

```
public <R, F extends Function<T, R>> Builder<T> withX(F getter, R returnValue) {...}
```

more strict then

```
public <R> Builder<T> with(Function<T, R> getter, R returnValue) {...}
```

This is a follow up on [Why is lambda return type not checked at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337639).
I found using the method `withX()` like

```
.withX(MyInterface::getLength, "I am not a Long")
```

produces the wanted compile time error:

> The type of getLength() from the type BuilderExample.MyInterface is long, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: String

while using the method `with()` does not.

### full example:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class SO58376589 {
  public static class Builder<T> {
    public <R, F extends Function<T, R>> Builder<T> withX(F getter, R returnValue) {
      return this;
    }

    public <R> Builder<T> with(Function<T, R> getter, R returnValue) {
      return this;
    }

  }

  static interface MyInterface {
    public Long getLength();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Builder<MyInterface> b = new Builder<MyInterface>();
    Function<MyInterface, Long> getter = MyInterface::getLength;
    b.with(getter, 2L);
    b.with(MyInterface::getLength, 2L);
    b.withX(getter, 2L);
    b.withX(MyInterface::getLength, 2L);
    b.with(getter, "No NUMBER"); // error
    b.with(MyInterface::getLength, "No NUMBER"); // NO ERROR !!
    b.withX(getter, "No NUMBER"); // error
    b.withX(MyInterface::getLength, "No NUMBER"); // error !!!
  }
}
```

> javac SO58376589.java

```
SO58376589.java:32: error: method with in class Builder<T> cannot be applied to given types;
    b.with(getter, "No NUMBER"); // error
     ^
  required: Function<MyInterface,R>,R
  found: Function<MyInterface,Long>,String
  reason: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: Long
    lower bounds: String
  where R,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R>with(Function<T,R>,R)
    T extends Object declared in class Builder
SO58376589.java:34: error: method withX in class Builder<T> cannot be applied to given types;
    b.withX(getter, "No NUMBER"); // error
     ^
  required: F,R
  found: Function<MyInterface,Long>,String
  reason: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: Long
    lower bounds: String
  where F,R,T are type-variables:
    F extends Function<MyInterface,R> declared in method <R,F>withX(F,R)
    R extends Object declared in method <R,F>withX(F,R)
    T extends Object declared in class Builder
SO58376589.java:35: error: incompatible types: cannot infer type-variable(s) R,F
    b.withX(MyInterface::getLength, "No NUMBER"); // error
           ^
    (argument mismatch; bad return type in method reference
      Long cannot be converted to String)
  where R,F,T are type-variables:
    R extends Object declared in method <R,F>withX(F,R)
    F extends Function<T,R> declared in method <R,F>withX(F,R)
    T extends Object declared in class Builder
3 errors
```

### Extended Example

The following example shows the different behaviour of method and type parameter boiled down to a Supplier. In addition it shows the difference to a Consumer behaviour for a type parameter. And it shows it does not make a difference wether it is a Consumer or Supplier for a method parameter.

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
interface TypeInference {

  Number getNumber();

  void setNumber(Number n);

  @FunctionalInterface
  interface Method<R> {
    TypeInference be(R r);
  }

  //Supplier:
  <R> R letBe(Supplier<R> supplier, R value);
  <R, F extends Supplier<R>> R letBeX(F supplier, R value);
  <R> Method<R> let(Supplier<R> supplier);  // return (x) -> this;

  //Consumer:
  <R> R lettBe(Consumer<R> supplier, R value);
  <R, F extends Consumer<R>> R lettBeX(F supplier, R value);
  <R> Method<R> lett(Consumer<R> consumer);


  public static void main(TypeInference t) {
    t.letBe(t::getNumber, (Number) 2); // Compiles :-)
    t.lettBe(t::setNumber, (Number) 2); // Compiles :-)
    t.letBe(t::getNumber, 2); // Compiles :-)
    t.lettBe(t::setNumber, 2); // Compiles :-)
    t.letBe(t::getNumber, "NaN"); // !!!! Compiles :-(
    t.lettBe(t::setNumber, "NaN"); // Does not compile :-)

    t.letBeX(t::getNumber, (Number) 2); // Compiles :-)
    t.lettBeX(t::setNumber, (Number) 2); // Compiles :-)
    t.letBeX(t::getNumber, 2); // !!! Does not compile  :-(
    t.lettBeX(t::setNumber, 2); // Compiles :-)
    t.letBeX(t::getNumber, "NaN"); // Does not compile :-)
    t.lettBeX(t::setNumber, "NaN"); // Does not compile :-)

    t.let(t::getNumber).be(2); // Compiles :-)
    t.lett(t::setNumber).be(2); // Compiles :-)
    t.let(t::getNumber).be("NaN"); // Does not compile :-)
    t.lett(t::setNumber).be("NaN"); // Does not compile :-)
  }
}
```

Comment: Because of the inference with the latter. Though both of them are base on the use-case one needs to implement. For yours, the former might be strict and good. For flexibility, someone else can prefer the latter.

Comment: Are you attempting to compile this in Eclipse? Searching for error strings of the format you pasted suggests this is an Eclipse (ecj) specific error. Do you get the same problem when compiling with raw `javac` or a build tool like Gradle or Maven?

Comment: @user31601 i added a full example with javac output. The error messages are little different formated but still eclipse and javac hold the same behaviour

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a really interesting question. The answer, I'm afraid, is complicated.

## tl;dr

Working out the difference involves some quite in-depth reading of Java's [type inference specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html), but basically boils down to this:

- All other things equal, the compiler infers the *most specific* type it can.
- However, if it can find *a* substitution for a type parameter that satisfies all the requirements, then compilation will succeed, however *vague* the substitution turns out to be.
- For `with` there is a (admittedly vague) substitution that satisfies all the requirements on `R`: `Serializable`
- For `withX`, the introduction of the additional type parameter `F` forces the compiler to resolve `R` first, without considering the constraint `F extends Function<T,R>`. `R` resolves to the (much more specific) `String` which then means that inference of `F` fails.

This last bullet point is the most important, but also the most hand-wavy. I can't think of a better concise way of phrasing it, so if you want more details, I suggest you read the full explanation below.

### Is this intended behaviour?

I'm gonna go out on a limb here, and say *no*.

I'm not suggesting there's a bug in the spec, more that (in the case of `withX`) the language designers have put their hands up and said *"there are some situations where type inference gets too hard, so we'll just fail"*. Even though the compiler's behaviour with respect to `withX` seems to be what you want, I would consider that to be an incidental side-effect of the current spec, rather than a positively intended design decision.

This matters, because it informs the question **Should I rely on this behaviour in my application design?** I would argue that you shouldn't, because you can't guarantee that future versions of the language will continue to behave this way.

While it's true that language designers try very hard not to break existing applications when they update their spec/design/compiler, the problem is that the behaviour you want to rely on is one where the compiler currently *fails* (i.e. not an *existing application*). Langauge updates turn non-compiling code into compiling code all the time. For example, the following code could be *guaranteed* not to compile in Java 7, but *would* compile in Java 8:

```
static Runnable x = () -> System.out.println();
```

Your use-case is no different.

Another reason I'd be cautious about using your `withX` method is the `F` parameter itself. Generally, a generic type parameter on a **method** (that doesn't appear in the return type) exists to bind the types of multiple parts of the signature together. It's saying:

*I don't care what `T` is, but want to be sure that wherever I use `T` it's the same type.*

Logically, then, we would expect each type parameter to appear at least twice in a method signature, otherwise "it's not doing anything". `F` in your `withX` only appears once in the signature, which suggests to me a use of a type parameter not inline with the *intent* of this feature of the language.

### An alternative implementation

One way to implement this in a slightly more "intended behaviour" way would be to split your `with` method up into a chain of 2:

```
public class Builder<T> {

    public final class With<R> {
        private final Function<T,R> method;

        private With(Function<T,R> method) {
            this.method = method;
        }

        public Builder<T> of(R value) {
            // TODO: Body of your old 'with' method goes here
            return Builder.this;
        }
    }

    public <R> With<R> with(Function<T,R> method) {
        return new With<>(method);
    }

}
```

This can then be used as follows:

```
b.with(MyInterface::getLong).of(1L); // Compiles
b.with(MyInterface::getLong).of("Not a long"); // Compiler error
```

This doesn't include an extraneous type parameter like your `withX` does. By breaking down the method into two signatures, it also better expresses the intent of what you're trying to do, from a type-safety point of view:

- The first method sets up a class (`With`) that *defines* the type based on the method reference.
- The scond method (`of`) *constrains* the type of the `value` to be compatible with what you previously set up.

The only way a future version of the language would be able to compile this is if the implemented full duck-typing, which seems unlikely.

**One final note to make this whole thing irrelevant:** *I think [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) (and in particular its stubbing functionality) might basically already do what you're trying to achieve with your "type safe generic builder". Maybe you could just use that instead?*

## The full(ish) explanation

I'm going to work through the [*type inference procedure*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html) for both `with` and `withX`. This is quite long, so take it slowly. Despite being long, I've still left quite a lot of details out. You may wish to refer to the spec for more details (follow the links) to convince yourself that I'm right (I may well have made a mistake).

Also, to simplify things a little, I'm going to use a more minimal code sample. The main difference is that it swaps out `Function` for `Supplier`, so there are less types and parameters in play. Here's a full snippet that reproduces the behaviour you described:

```java
public class TypeInference {

    static long getLong() { return 1L; }

    static <R> void with(Supplier<R> supplier, R value) {}
    static <R, F extends Supplier<R>> void withX(F supplier, R value) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        with(TypeInference::getLong, "Not a long");       // Compiles
        withX(TypeInference::getLong, "Also not a long"); // Does not compile
    }

}
```

Let's work through the type [*applicability inference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1) and [*type inference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2.) procedure for each method invocation in turn:

### `with`

We have:

```java
with(TypeInference::getLong, "Not a long");
```

The initial bound set, *B<sub>0</sub>*, is:

- `R <: Object`

All parameter expressions are [*pertinent to applicability*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2).

Hence, the initial constraint set for [*applicability inference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1), *C*, is:

- `TypeInference::getLong` *is compatible with* `Supplier<R>`
- `"Not a long"` *is compatible with* `R`

This [*reduces*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2) to bound set *B<sub>2</sub>* of:

- `R <: Object` (from *B<sub>0</sub>*)
- `Long <: R` (from the first constraint)
- `String <: R` (from the second constraint)

Since this does not contain the bound '*false*', and (I assume) [*resolution*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4) of `R` succeeds (giving `Serializable`), then the invocation is applicable.

So, we move on to [*invocation type inference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2.).

The new constraint set, *C*, with associated *input* and *output* variables, is:

- `TypeInference::getLong` *is compatible with* `Supplier<R>`

  - Input variables: *none*
  - Output variables: `R`

This contains no interdependencies between *input* and *output* variables, so can be [*reduced*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2) in a single step, and the final bound set, *B<sub>4</sub>*, is the same as *B<sub>2</sub>*. Hence, [*resolution*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4) succeeds as before, and the compiler breathes a sigh of relief!

### `withX`

We have:

```java
withX(TypeInference::getLong, "Also not a long");
```

The initial bound set, *B<sub>0</sub>*, is:

- `R <: Object`
- `F <: Supplier<R>`

Only the second parameter expression is [*pertinent to applicability*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.2). The first one (`TypeInference::getLong`) is not, because it meets the following condition:

> If `m` is a generic method and the method invocation does not provide explicit type arguments, an explicitly typed lambda expression or an exact method reference expression for which the corresponding target type (as derived from the signature of `m`) is a type parameter of `m`.

Hence, the initial constraint set for [*applicability inference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.1), *C*, is:

- `"Also not a long"` *is compatible with* `R`

This [*reduces*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2) to bound set *B<sub>2</sub>* of:

- `R <: Object` (from *B<sub>0</sub>*)
- `F <: Supplier<R>` (from *B<sub>0</sub>*)
- `String <: R` (from the constraint)

Again, since this does not contain the bound '*false*', and [*resolution*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4) of `R` succeeds (giving `String`), then the invocation is applicable.

[*Invocation type inference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2.) once more...

This time, the new constraint set, *C*, with associated *input* and *output* variables, is:

- `TypeInference::getLong` *is compatible with* `F`

  - Input variables: `F`
  - Output variables: *none*

Again, we have no interdependencies between *input* and *output* variables. However this time, there **is** an *input variable* (`F`), so we must [resolve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.4) this before attempting [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2). So, we start with our bound set *B<sub>2</sub>*.

1. We determine a subset `V` as follows:

   > Given a set of inference variables to resolve, let `V` be the union of this set and all variables upon which the resolution of at least one variable in this set depends.

   By the second bound in *B<sub>2</sub>*, the resolution of `F` depends on `R`, so `V := {F, R}`.
2. We pick a subset of `V` according to the rule:

   > let `{ α1, ..., αn }` be a non-empty subset of uninstantiated variables in `V` such that i) for all `i (1 ≤ i ≤ n)`, if `αi` depends on the resolution of a variable `β`, then either `β` has an instantiation or there is some `j` such that `β = αj`; and ii) there exists no non-empty proper subset of `{ α1, ..., αn }` with this property.

   The only subset of `V` that satisfies this property is `{R}`.
3. Using the third bound (`String <: R`) we instantiate `R = String` and incorporate this into our bound set. `R` is now resolved, and the second bound effectively becomes `F <: Supplier<String>`.
4. Using the (revised) second bound, we instantiate `F = Supplier<String>`. `F` is now resolved.

Now that `F` is resolved, we can proceed with [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2), using the new constraint:

1. `TypeInference::getLong` *is compatible with* `Supplier<String>`
2. ...reduces to `Long` *is compatible with* `String`
3. ...which reduces to *false*

... and we get a compiler error!

---

## Additional notes on the 'Extended Example'

The **Extended Example** in the question looks at a few interesting cases that aren't directly covered by the workings above:

- Where the value type is a *subtype* of the method return type (`Integer <: Number`)
- Where the functional interface is contravariant in the inferred type (i.e. `Consumer` rather than `Supplier`)

In particular, 3 of the given invocations stand out as potentially suggesting 'different' compiler behaviour to that described in the explanations:

```java
t.lettBe(t::setNumber, "NaN"); // Does not compile :-)

t.letBeX(t::getNumber, 2); // !!! Does not compile  :-(
t.lettBeX(t::setNumber, 2); // Compiles :-)
```

The second of these 3 will go through exactly the same inference process as `withX` above (just replace `Long` with `Number` and `String` with `Integer`). This illustrates yet another reason why you shouldn't rely on this failed type inference behaviour for your class design, as the failure to compile here is likely *not* a desirable behaviour.

For the other 2 (and indeed any of the other invocations involving a `Consumer` you wish to work through), the behaviour should be apparent if you work through the type inference procedure laid out for one of the methods above (i.e. `with` for the first, `withX` for the third). There's just one small change you need to take note of:

- The constraint on the first parameter (`t::setNumber` *is compatible with* `Consumer<R>`) will [*reduce*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2) to `R <: Number` instead of `Number <: R` as it does for `Supplier<R>`. This is described in the linked documentation on reduction.

I leave it as an excercise for the reader to carfully work through one of the above procedures, armed with this piece of additional knowledge, to demonstrate to themselves exactly why a particular invocation does or doesn't compile.

Comment: Very in-depth, well researched and formulated. Thanks!

Comment: @user31601
Can you please point out where the difference of Supplier to Consumer comes into play. I added an Extended Example in the original question for that. It shows  covariant, contravariant and invariant behavior for the different version of letBe(), letBeX() and let().be() depending on Supplier/Consumer.

Comment: @jukzi I've added a few additional notes, but you should have enough info to work through these new examples yourself.

Comment: Thats intersting: so many special cases in 18.2.1. for lambdas and method references where i would not have expected any special case for them at all from my naive understanding. And probably no ordinary developer would expect.

Comment: Well, I guess the reason is that with lambdas and method references, the compiler needs to decide what proper type the lambda should implement - it has to make a choice! For example, `TypeInference::getLong` could imlement `Supplier<Long>` or `Supplier<Serializable>` or `Supplier<Number>` etc, but crucially it can only implement one of them (just like any other class)!

This is different from all other expressions, where the implemented types are all known up front, and the compiler just has to work out whether one of them meets the constraint requirements.