# Why can Java not infer a supertype?

Tags: java, type-inference

We all know Long extends `Number`. So why does this not compile?

And how to define the method `with` so that the program compiles without any manual cast?

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class Builder<T> {
  static public interface MyInterface {
    Number getNumber();
    Long getLong();
  }

  public <F extends Function<T, R>, R> Builder<T> with(F getter, R returnValue) {
    return null;//TODO
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // works:
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getLong, 4L);
    // works:
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, (Number) 4L);
    // works:
    new Builder<MyInterface>().<Function<MyInterface, Number>, Number> with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
    // works:
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with((Function<MyInterface, Number>) MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
    // compilation error: Cannot infer ...
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
    // compilation error: Cannot infer ...
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, Long.valueOf(4));
    // compiles but also involves typecast (and Casting Number to Long is not even safe):
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with( myInterface->(Long) myInterface.getNumber(), 4L);
    // compiles but also involves manual conversion:
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(myInterface -> myInterface.getNumber().longValue(), 4L);
    // compiles (compiler you are kidding me?): 
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(castToFunction(MyInterface::getNumber), 4L);

  }
  static <X, Y> Function<X, Y> castToFunction(Function<X, Y> f) {
    return f;
  }

}
```

> - Cannot infer type argument(s) for `<F, R> with(F, R)`
> - The type of getNumber() from the type Builder.MyInterface is Number, this is incompatible with the descriptor's return type: Long

For use case see: [Why is lambda return type not checked at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337639/)

Comment: Can you post `MyInterface`?

Comment: its already inside the class

Comment: Hmm I tried `<F extends Function<T, R>, R, S extends R> Builder<T> with(F getter, S returnValue)` but got `java.lang.Number cannot be converted to java.lang.Long)`, which is surprising because I don't see where the compiler gets the idea that the return value from `getter` will need to be converted to `returnValue`.

Comment: @jukzi OK. Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: Changing `Number getNumber()` to `<A extends Number> A getNumber()` makes stuff work. No idea whether this is what you wanted. As others have said the issue is that `MyInterface::getNumber` could be a function that returns `Double` for example and not `Long`. Your declaration does not allow the compiler to narrow the return type based on other information present. By using a generic return type you allow the compiler to do so, hence it works.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta your explanation does not let me understand why "with(castToFunction(MyInterface::getNumber), 4L)" compiles. And obviously the usecase of a builder is not to use "A extends Number". Interesting idea though.

Answer (score 10):

This expression :

```
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
```

can be rewritten as :

```
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(myInterface -> myInterface.getNumber(), 4L);
```

Taking into account method signature :

```
public <F extends Function<T, R>, R> Builder<T> with(F getter, R returnValue)
```

- `R` will be inferred to `Long`
- `F` will be `Function<MyInterface, Long>`

and you pass a method reference which will be infered as `Function<MyInterface, Number>` This is the key - **how should compiler predict that you actually want to return `Long` from a function with such signature?** It will not do the downcasting for you.

Since `Number` is superclass of `Long` and `Number` is not necessairly a `Long` (this is why it does not compile) - you would have to cast explicitly on your own :

```
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(myInterface -> (Long) myInterface.getNumber(), 4L);
```

making `F` to be `Function<MyIinterface, Long>` or pass generic arguments explicitly during method call as you did :

```
new Builder<MyInterface>().<Function<MyInterface, Number>, Number> with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
```

and know `R` will be seen as `Number` and code will compile.

Comment: Thats an interesting typecast. But still i am searching for a definition of the method "with" which will make the caller compile without any cast. Anyway thanks for that idea.

Comment: @jukzi You can't. It does not matter how your `with` is written. You have `MJyInterface::getNumber` has type `Function<MyInterface, Number>` so `R=Number` and then you also have `R=Long` from the other argument (remember that Java literals are not polymorphic!). At this point the compiler stops because it's not always possible to convert a `Number` to a `Long`. The only way to fix this is to change `MyInterface` to use `<A extends Number> Number` as return type, this makes the compiler have `R=A` and then `R=Long` and since `A extends Number` it can substitute `A=Long`

Answer (score 4):

The key to your error is in the generic declaration of the type of `F`: `F extends Function<T, R>`. The statement that does not work is: `new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);` First, you have a new `Builder<MyInterface>`. The declaration of the class therefore implies `T = MyInterface`. As per your declaration of `with`, `F` must be a `Function<T, R>`, which is a `Function<MyInterface, R>` in this situation. Therefore, the parameter `getter` must take a `MyInterface` as parameter (satisfied by the method references `MyInterface::getNumber` and `MyInterface::getLong`), and return `R`, which must be the same type as the second parameter to the function `with`. Now, let's see if this holds for all of your cases:

```
// T = MyInterface, F = Function<MyInterface, Long>, R = Long
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getLong, 4L);
// T = MyInterface, F = Function<MyInterface, Number>, R = Number
// 4L explicitly widened to Number
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, (Number) 4L);
// T = MyInterface, F = Function<MyInterface, Number>, R = Number
// 4L implicitly widened to Number
new Builder<MyInterface>().<Function<MyInterface, Number>, Number>with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
// T = MyInterface, F = Function<MyInterface, Number>, R = Number
// 4L implicitly widened to Number
new Builder<MyInterface>().with((Function<MyInterface, Number>) MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
// T = MyInterface, F = Function<MyInterface, Number>, R = Long
// F = Function<T, not R> violates definition, therefore compilation error occurs
// Compiler cannot infer type of method reference and 4L at the same time, 
// so it keeps the type of 4L as Long and attempts to infer a match for MyInterface::getNumber,
// only to find that the types don't match up
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
```

You can "fix" this problem with the following options:

```
// stick to Long
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getLong, 4L);
// stick to Number
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, (Number) 4L);
// explicitly convert the result of getNumber:
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(myInstance -> (Long) myInstance.getNumber(), 4L);
// explicitly convert the result of getLong:
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(myInterface -> (Number) myInterface.getLong(), (Number) 4L);
```

Beyond this point, it's mostly a design decision for which option reduces code complexity for your particular application, so choose whatever fits you best.

The reason that you cannot do this without casting lies in the following, [from the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> Boxing conversion treats expressions of a primitive type as expressions of a corresponding reference type. Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the *boxing conversions*:
>
> - From type boolean to type Boolean
> - From type byte to type Byte
> - From type short to type Short
> - From type char to type Character
> - From type int to type Integer
> - From type long to type Long
> - From type float to type Float
> - From type double to type Double
> - From the null type to the null type

As you can clearly see, there is no implicit boxing conversion from long to Number, and the widening conversion from Long to Number can only occur when the compiler is sure that it requires a Number and not a Long. As there is a conflict between the method reference that requires a Number and the 4L that provides a Long, the compiler (for some reason???) unable to make the logical leap that Long is-a Number and deduce that `F` is a `Function<MyInterface, Number>`.

Instead, I managed to resolve the problem by slightly editing the function signature:

```
public <R> Builder<T> with(Function<T, ? super R> getter, R returnValue) {
  return null;//TODO
}
```

After this change, the following occurs:

```
// doesn't work, as it should not work
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getLong, (Number), 4L);
// works, as it always did
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getLong, 4L);
// works, as it should work
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, (Number)4L);
// works, as you wanted
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
```

**Edit:**
After spending some more time on it, it's annoyingly difficult to enforce getter-based type safety. Here's a working example that uses setter methods to enforce a builder's type-safety:

```
public class Builder<T> {

  static public interface MyInterface {
    //setters
    void number(Number number);
    void Long(Long Long);
    void string(String string);

    //getters
    Number number();
    Long Long();
    String string();
  }
  // whatever object we're building, let's say it's just a MyInterface for now...
  private T buildee = (T) new MyInterface() {
    private String string;
    private Long Long;
    private Number number;
    public void number(Number number)
    {
      this.number = number;
    }
    public void Long(Long Long)
    {
      this.Long = Long;
    }
    public void string(String string)
    {
      this.string = string;
    }
    public Number number()
    {
      return this.number;
    }
    public Long Long()
    {
      return this.Long;
    }
    public String string()
    {
      return this.string;
    }
  };

  public <R> Builder<T> with(BiConsumer<T, R> setter, R val)
  {
    setter.accept(this.buildee, val); // take the buildee, and set the appropriate value
    return this;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // works:
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::Long, 4L);
    // works:
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::number, (Number) 4L);
    // compile time error, as it shouldn't work
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::Long, (Number) 4L);
    // works, as it always did
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::Long, 4L);
    // works, as it should
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::number, (Number)4L);
    // works, as you wanted
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::number, 4L);
    // compile time error, as you wanted
    new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::number, "blah");
  }
}
```

Provided the type-safe ability to construct an object, hopefully at some point in the future we'll be able to return an [immutable data object](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) from the builder (maybe by adding a `toRecord()` method to the interface, and specifying the builder as a `Builder<IntermediaryInterfaceType, RecordType>`), so you don't even have to worry about the resulting object being modified. Honestly, it's an absolute shame that it requires so much effort to get a type-safe field-flexible builder, but it's probably impossible without some new features, code generation, or an annoying amount of reflection.

Comment: Thanks for all your work but i do not see any improvement towards avoiding the manual typecast. My naive understanding is that a compiler should be able to infer (i.e. typecast) everything that a human can.

Comment: @jukzi My naive understanding is the same, but for whatever reason it doesn't work that way. I've come up with a workaround that pretty much achieves the desired effect, though

Comment: Thanks again. But your new proposal is too wide (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58337639/) since it allows compilation of ".with(MyInterface::getNumber, "I AM NOT A NUMBER")";

Comment: your sentence "Compiler cannot infer type of method reference and 4L at the same time" is cool. But i just want it the other way arround. the compiler should try Number based on the first parameter and do a widening to Number of the second parameter.

Comment: @jukzi I'm thinking it's going to be very nasty to get that type safety, because Java will implicitly widen the type to Object if it must (and it must) when trying to accept String. I'll see what I can do, but no guarantees

Comment: Java is being tragic again :( Had to find another wonky workaround, and it barely even fits the original intent >.<

Comment: WHAAAAAAAAAAAT? Why does BiConsumer work as intended while Function does not? I do not get the idea. I admit this is exactly the typesafety i wanted but unfortunatlly does not work with getters. WHY WHY WHY.

Comment: @jukzi tragic... :( The idea is that the setters already define the bounds they want in the declaration of the setter. With getters, you *can't* stop Java from automatically widening types up to Object. The only way to restrict it is to specify the maximum acceptable parameter type yourself or cast the parameter.

Comment: I guess it has todo with the assumption that return types are covariant while parameters are contravariant. But i do not understand how the compiler knows that a type parameter is ment to be a return type or a parameter. Where is that hardcoded? Both BiConsumer and Function just have two parameters. Is it information of the methodreference somehow which of them is co/contravariant??

Comment: I think it's because `val` is used as an argument to another function in the body of the `with` function, and so that constrains its type to prevent the widening inference to `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the compiler has used the value 4L to decide that R is Long, and getNumber() returns a Number, which is not necessarily a Long.

But I'm not sure why the value takes precedence over the method...

Answer (score 0):

The Java compiler is in general not good at inferring multiple/nested generic types or wildcards. Often I cannot get something to compile without using a helper function to capture or infer some of the types.

But, do you really need to capture the exact type of `Function` as `F`? If not, maybe the following works, and as you can see, also seems to work with subtypes of `Function`.

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class Builder<T> {
    public interface MyInterface {
        Number getNumber();
        Long getLong();
    }

    public <R> Builder<T> with(Function<T, R> getter, R returnValue) {
        return null;
    }

    // example subclass of Function
    private static UnaryOperator<String> stringFunc = (s) -> (s + ".");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // works
        new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
        // works
        new Builder<String>().with(stringFunc, "s");

    }
}
```

Comment: "with(MyInterface::getNumber, "NOT A NUMBER")" should not compile

Answer (score 0):

The most interesting part lies in the difference between those 2 lines, I think:

```
// works:
new Builder<MyInterface>().<Function<MyInterface, Number>, Number> with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
// compilation error: Cannot infer ...
new Builder<MyInterface>().with(MyInterface::getNumber, 4L);
```

In the first case, the `T` is explicitly `Number`, so `4L` is also a `Number`, no problem. In the second case, `4L` is a `Long`, so `T` is a `Long`, so your function is not compatible, and Java cannot know if you meant `Number` or `Long`.

Answer (score 0):

With the following signature:

```
public <R> Test<T> with(Function<T, ? super R> getter, R returnValue)
```

all your examples compile, except the third, which explicitly requires the method to have two type variables.

The reason that your version doesn't work, is because Java's method references do not have one specific type. Instead, they have the type which is required in the given context. In your case, `R` is inferred to be `Long` because of the `4L`, but the getter cannot have the type `Function<MyInterface,Long>` because in Java, generic types are invariant in their arguments.

Comment: Your code would compile `with( getNumber,"NO NUMBER")` which is not desired. Also it is not true that generics are always invariant (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58378661/9549750 for a prove that generics of setters behave other then those of getters)

Comment: @jukzi Ah, my solution was already proposed by Avi. Too bad... :-). By the way, it is true that we can assign a `Thing<Cat>` to a `Thing<? extends Animal>` variable, but for real covariance I would expect that a `Thing<Cat>` can be assigned to a `Thing<Animal>`. Other languages, such as Kotlin, do allow to define co- and contravariant type variables.